# Associating Controllers with Angular Scope Objects explicitly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

From the AngularJS documentation *[Understanding controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)*:

> ### Associating Controllers with Angular Scope Objects
>
> You can associate Controllers with scope objects implicitly via the
>   *ngController directive* or *$route service*.

Those two approaches are well known and mainly used across AngurlaJS applications.

What draw my attention is this part found in *[Developer Guide / Understanding the Controller Component](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller)*:

> ### Associating Controllers with Angular Scope Objects
>
> You can associate controllers with scope objects explicitly via the
>   **scope.$new** api or implicitly via the *ngController directive* or *$route
>   service*.

So in addition to implicit association of Controller with scope there is mentioned also explicit way by using **scope.$new** api.

I am aware  that **scope.$new** is used to create new [isolated] scope but I somehow don't understand how exactly is it related to explicit association of controller with scope.

It would be great to see some practical use case and/or more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's primarily used during testing when you want to construct a controller directly and do something with it.

You can use the [$controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24controller) service to do this:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
var ctrl = $controller(MyAwesomeController, { $scope: scope });
```

Now I can manipulate the `scope` variable directly and check for side effects:

```
scope.foo = 'bar'
scope.$digest();

expect(scope.bar).toBe('YEAH BABY!!!');
```

The [$controller](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24controller) service will instantiate a controller with all of the dependencies injected like you would expect. **It also allows you to pass in a hash of locals that will override any of the dependencies with something you provide explicitly.**

Again, this is very useful for testing because you can swap out a service with a mock if needed.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Perfect! +1